# cmake: mingw32-make.exe No rule to make target

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, mingw-w64, msys2

Как узнать откуда cmake берет префикс "C:/building/"? Этой директории никогда не существовало. Пытаюсь статически линковать библиотеки mingw в exe.

```
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: F:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe --build c:/Users/kerne/Desktop/Dropper/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/building/msys64/mingw64/lib/libexpat.dll.a', needed by 'dropper.exe'.  Stop.
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/dropper.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:129: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
    project(dropper)

    include(GNUInstallDirs)
    get_filename_component(mingw64_share ${CMAKE_ROOT} DIRECTORY)
    get_filename_component(mingw64 ${mingw64_share} DIRECTORY)
    set(mingw64_include ${mingw64}/include)
    set(mingw64_lib ${mingw64}/lib)
    set(mingw64_bin ${mingw64}/bin)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${mingw64} CACHE PATH "Cmake prefix" FORCE)

    message(STATUS "!-- ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}")

    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static-libexpat -static")

    # Create executable
    file(GLOB 
              CPP_SRC "src/*.cpp")

    include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
    link_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")


    include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR})
    link_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR})

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_SRC})
```

CMake установлен с помощью MSYS2. Все переменные окружения GnuInstallDirs правильные и указывают на дерево каталогов mingw64/ (То есть mingw64/bin, mingw64/include и тд.)

**update**:

Я нашел похожую [проблему](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/1864). Всё дело в пакете libxml2-2.9.4. Но msys2 использует версию 2.9.9-4 а mingw64: mingw-w64-x86_64-libxml2 2.9.9-2. Я даже пробовал перемещать библиотеку libexpat.dll.a в каталог C:/building/msys64/mingw64/lib/ но получал то же вывод: 
`mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/building/msys64/mingw64/lib/libexpat.dll.a', needed by ...`

Проблема по-прежнему не решена!

**update2**:

Оказалось, [проблема](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/1670) вообще во всех библиотеках MSYS2. Не совсем понимаю как, но, видимо, собирали библиотеки с hard-coded директориями.. Попробую решить перемещением msys2 по адресу: с:\building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась перемещением MSYS2 в директорию `C:\building`. То есть теперь вся инфраструктура выглядит так: `C:\building\msys64\mingw64\bin`. Надеюсь, в будущем, разрабочики MSYS2 не будут жестко задавать пути для собранных библиотек.